# modify data in struct in python

Tags: python, struct

I would like to know if it's possible to modify an already made struct.
What I want is to calculate the CRC of `header` and then write the CRC value to the 3rd position in `header`.

```
import struct
import crcmod

crcfunc = crcmod.mkCrcFun(0x112, 0x00, 0x00)
header = struct.pack('!hii', 1, 2, 0)
crcvalue = crcfunc(header)
```

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the result of calling `struct.pack` is to create a byte string, it is immutable.

You could either splice the crc into the byte string by slicing it, or create a new byte string:

```
header2 = struct.pack('!hii', 1, 2, crcvalue)
```

Alternatively, if you want to create a mutable byte string, you could create a buffer, and use `struct.pack_into` instead of `struct.pack`.

Comment: `pack_into` is the way to go. +1

Answer (score 2):

You can not do it directly: `struct.pack` returns a `bytes` object, which like `str`, is immutable. However, you can very easily create the updated object:

```
header = header[:-4] + c.to_bytes(4, byteorder=sys.byteorder)
```

If you really meant to compute the CRC value on everything excluding the last element, you can do something like this instead:

```
header = struct.pack('!hi', 1, 2)
header += crcfunc(header).to_bytes(4, byteorder=sys.byteorder)
```